# How to add ajaxoptions to form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I have ajaxoptions included in the following form:

```
   <form id="" action="<%=Url.Action("ChangePassword",new{Action="ChangePassword" }) %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: You will post your form with ajax call and you're asking how to do it?

Comment: I want to dynamically update a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

What javascript (if any) library are you using?

**Generally you set the options in script and not C# code.**

To answer your comment:

In JQuery w/ [Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) like:

```
var options = { 
       target: '#output2' // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
}

$(function() {
   $("form").submit(function() { 

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        return false; 
   });
});
```

Comment: Can I have an example how to do that?

Comment: ... look at the answer again.